# Adding new Django app - Getting 404 page not found

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I have created a directory called vsdk which includes service_development (a voice application) and my newly created application called dashboard. Unfortunately I can’t seem to get the main page of dashboard to work. I get a 404 error when trying to access 127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/, while doing everything similar to what I’ve done with service_development.

Would someone be able to help me?

Vsdk\settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'vsdk.service_development.apps.ServiceDevelopmentConfig',
    'vsdk.dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
    'storages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',    
]
```

Vsdk\dashboard\apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class DashboardConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'vsdk.dashboard'
    verbose_name = _("Dashboards")
```

Vsdk\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf import settings


from django.urls import include, path

admin.site.site_header = _("Petrichor Rain Service")

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^vxml/', include('vsdk.service_development.urls')),
    url(r'^vxml/', include('vsdk.dashboard.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Vsdk\dashboard\urls.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: There aren't any url patterns for `r'^dashboard/'` in your project's `urls.py`. Try going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/vxml/` instead. Perhaps you want to change one of the `r'^vxml/' to `r'^dashboard/' for one of the `include()`s so that they don't clash.

Comment: Can you show us your folder structure?

Comment: `url(r'^vxml/', include('vsdk.dashboard.urls'))` seems like a simple typo.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you! Your suggestion to change the r'^vxml/' to r'^dashboard/' for my second url pattern solved it! I can now visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/ without an error